# BCS to connect to a WCF Service and use bindings from a config file

Tags: sharepoint-2010, unity-container, bcs, sharepoint-search

I have data exposed from a webservice which is wcf. I already have method calls to call GetAllItems and GetItem(id). I want to use SharePoint Search to index them so that it can be easier to search. Our application uses Unity as dependency injection. The web.config of the SharePoint application has already been set up for calling this webservice and the web.config is updated using a feature.

Would it be possible to use the same code? the BCS .net connector is deployed as a Farm Feature, so where will it read the servicemodel settings? should i update the web.config of central administration application?